# Mozilla reset focus on back

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, mozilla

I have this Mozilla bug which keeps focused the last button you clicked on the previous page when you go back from the current page. Is there any way I can reset the focus on page load or something like this?

Comment: Any example?...